# Symfony2: Custom validator only warning about a validation constraint

Tags: javascript, php, validation, symfony

I need a really simple Symfony 2 validator: it must check if a field's contents isn't blank, and if it's a valid Spain VAT number.

Building this validator is straightforward and I have no problems with it. But I want a non-standard validator behavior: I want that when the VAT number is incorrect, a simple text (something like "Warning: This VAT number is invalid") appears at the side of the field, BUT the content must be saved on the database.

Is this possible? Or this shouldn't be a validator? Maybe instead of a validator I should write some JavaScript or a Twig component?

Comment: any code for the validator you have written?

Comment: It won't work, because `if($form->isValid())` will fail. Use your custom JS validator

Comment: @Rooneyl: is like the cookbook example (http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html), but changing the validate function... There's no much code to show...

Comment: @bartek: Yes, this is what I'm thinking... But I'm asking this because maybe there is some workaroud to fail a validation and still keep the form valid... But it seems that there isn't any workaround...

Comment: you just check the errors if $form->valid() fails, and if there is an error for your VAT field continue, else reshow form with errors

Comment: @mHouses Let `Validator` do his job. Create `checker` to check the VAT value. Workarounds are evil ;)

Comment: @bartek What's a `checker`? I couldn't find anything in the Symfony documentation. There is only the `UserCheckerInterface`.